# Problem regarding to solve "6 nonlinear dynamic system of first order differential equation" analytically ( approximated )

Tags: taylor-expansion, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory, analytic-functions, oscillatory-integral

I have some problem to solve, Problem is regarding to solve "6 nonlinear dynamic system of first order differential equation" analytically ( approximated answer):-

1) Can I solve this system of equation by using Perturbation technique, if possible can you suggest some example or article where more than 3 system of equation is solved.

2) If any other approximated technique

[Diffrential equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIlMN.jpg)

Comment: The system you have bracketed in your image is linear...

Comment: Possible typo in the source:  What's $u_0$?

Comment: from top 3,4 and 5th equation is nonlinear (terms ic ib have an exponential term on right side ic and ib values given).  ic and ib has a dependent variable in terms of u1 u2 u3

Comment: This is a linear system with nine independent variables.  Some of those variables have side relations (the right column).  Solving the linear system, then imposing the side conditions (to reduce the space of solutions) would be a smart thing to try.

Comment: u0 is an external unit step.

Comment: this system has six independent variable (i1, i2, u1 u2 u3 u4) rest is known.  I try to reduce but it is not reducing in polynomial